# Why is my upload-release-asset action on GitHub failing?

Tags: github, github-actions, github-actions-artifacts

In my release script I have these actions, among others:

```
- name: Create Release
    id: createRelease
    uses: actions/create-release@v1
    env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
    with:
        tag_name: ${{steps.createReleaseTag.outputs.string}}
        release_name: ${{github.sha}}
        body: Auto-generated prerelease build
        prerelease: true
# yes, we really do have to download the artifact we just uploaded; this job can't see it automatically
- name: Download Artifact
    uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
    with:
        name: FrEee.WinForms-${{steps.createReleaseTag.outputs.string}}
        path: FrEee.WinForms-${{steps.createReleaseTag.outputs.string}}
- name: Upload Release Asset
    uses: actions/upload-release-asset@v1
    env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
    with:
        upload_url: "${{ steps.createRelease.outputs.upload_url }}" # This pulls from the CREATE RELEASE step above, referencing it's ID to get its outputs object, which include a `upload_url`. See this blog post for more info: https://jasonet.co/posts/new-features-of-github-actions/#passing-data-to-future-steps 
        asset_path: FrEee.WinForms-${{steps.createReleaseTag.outputs.string}}
        asset_name: FrEee.WinForms-${{steps.createReleaseTag.outputs.string}}
        asset_content_type: application/zip
```

However when I run it I get this output:

```
Run actions/upload-release-asset@v1
  with:
    upload_url: https://uploads.github.com/repos/ekolis/FrEee/releases/37114727/assets{?name,label}
    asset_path: FrEee.WinForms-cc1b19f204
    asset_name: FrEee.WinForms-cc1b19f204
    asset_content_type: application/zip
  env:
    DOTNET_ROOT: C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\dotnet
    GITHUB_TOKEN: ***
Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
```

What's wrong? Is the artifact somehow being treated as a directory instead of a zip file? Does this job not have permission to read the artifact that was created earlier in the action? Is something wrong with the upload URL? (Why does it have `{?name,label}` in it? It's just the output from the `createRelease` job...)

Comment: What is `FrEee.WinForms-cc1b19f204`?  _Is_ it a directory?

Comment: It's the name of the artifact that I'm trying to package as an asset. I'll edit my post to provide more of the actions as context.

Comment: I just want to know what is on the filesystem.  You say it’s a zip file, but the name doesn’t it end in `.zip`?  What’s the output of `ls -FlasR`?

Comment: I think I might understand what you’re trying to do?  Are you running the upload-artifact step and trying to upload the zip that _it creates_ as a release asset?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to upload an artifact, then upload the artifact as a release asset. For whatever reason I had to download the artifact that I'd just uploaded in order for it to be visible to the upload-release-asset action; let me add that action too.

Comment: On the filesystem? I have no idea, this is on GitHub and I wish I knew how to get a listing of what's on the filesystem, that would make my life so much easier! 

Answer (score 2):

It's rather hard to tell what's going on *precisely* from your question, without seeing the complete workflow file or - better - the workflow run.  But GitHub Actions is not a black box - it's just a machine that runs the things that you tell it to run, so if you're asking:

> Is the artifact somehow being treated as a directory instead of a zip file?

Then you can just tell it to show you the directory listings.  For example: your `upload-release-asset` action is trying to upload a *file* named `FrEee.WinForms-${{steps.createReleaseTag.outputs.string}}`.

But the run complains that this file is a *directory*.  Which certainly *seems reasonable* given the step before it that downloads a workflow artifact that doesn't have the name `.zip` in it.  You can find out for yourself:

```
# A previous step has uploaded an artifact to this workflow run.
# Download it to the current virtual machine so that we can create
# a release with it.
- name: Download Artifact
  uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
  with:
    name: FrEee.WinForms-${{steps.createReleaseTag.outputs.string}}
    path: FrEee.WinForms-${{steps.createReleaseTag.outputs.string}}

# See what we actually downloaded...
- run: ls -FlasR "FrEee.WinForms-${{steps.createReleaseTag.outputs.string}}"
```

I don't *know*, but I suspect that you'll find that the error message is correct and you have a *directory* on disk, not a zip file.  In that case, zip it up and upload it as an artifact.  You can zip it just like you would on the console.

Then be sure to change your use of the `upload-release-asset` action to specify the name of the `.zip` file.

```
# Since we have a directory, create a zip
- run: zip -r "FrEee.WinForms-${{steps.createReleaseTag.outputs.string}}.zip" "FrEee.WinForms-${{steps.createReleaseTag.outputs.string}}"

# Now upload the zip file
- name: Upload Release Asset
  uses: actions/upload-release-asset@v1
  env:
    GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
  with:
    upload_url: "${{ steps.createRelease.outputs.upload_url }}" # This pulls from the CREATE RELEASE step above, referencing it's ID to get its outputs object, which include a `upload_url`. See this blog post for more info: https://jasonet.co/posts/new-features-of-github-actions/#passing-data-to-future-steps 
    asset_path: FrEee.WinForms-${{steps.createReleaseTag.outputs.string}}.zip
    asset_name: FrEee.WinForms-${{steps.createReleaseTag.outputs.string}}.zip
    asset_content_type: application/zip
```

Comment: Wait, you can run shell commands as part of a job? That would definitely be handy! My job is running on a Windows server so I suppose I'd want to use `dir` instead of `ls`, but thanks! 